# Android RuntimeException onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I've an application that you can show and close several Dialogs with:

```
showDialog(...)
removeDialog(...)
```

I play a little bit with the application and when there is no any Dialog on the screen, I press the menu button and I go to the main android screen.

After a while, I enter again into my application and sometimes, I get this RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity#onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id 4
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity#onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id 4
    at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:878)
    at android.app.Activity.restoreManagedDialogs(Activity.java:867)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:815)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
    ... 11 more
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE, more information:

The current onCreateDialog implementation is:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
 Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 if(id == 4){
  b.setMessage(...);
  b.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
    Intent i = new Intent(Current.this, Another.class);
    startActivity(i);
   }
  });
  return b.create();
 }
 return null;
}
```

In order to call this function I do:

```
removeDialog(4);
showDialog(4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experiencing this same issue (and finding that calling `removeDialog` from within `onPause` doesn't work reliably), I developed a workaround that seems to function (although it's admittedly a hack).

As seen in the [grepcode link posted by antslava](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/app/Activity.java), in method `performRestoreInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState` is called right before `restoreManagedDialogs` and is passed the same instance of `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

```
final void performRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    restoreManagedDialogs(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Thus, there is opportunity to modify the `Bundle savedInstanceState` that is passed to `restoreManagedDialogs` from within the `onRestoreInstanceState` method.

To prevent any and all managed dialogs from being restored, one could implement `onRestoreInstanceState` in the following way:

```
// This same variable is defined as private in the Activity class. I need
// access to it, so I redefine it here.
private static final String SAVED_DIALOGS_TAG = "android:savedDialogs";

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final Bundle b = savedInstanceState.getBundle(SAVED_DIALOGS_TAG);
    if (null != b) {
        savedInstanceState.remove(SAVED_DIALOGS_TAG);
    }
}
```

This causes the `Bundle` referenced by key `"android:savedDialogs"` to be removed from `Bundle savedInstanceState`, which subsequently causes the call to `restoreManagedDialogs` to immediately return when it finds that this key cannot be found:

```
private void restoreManagedDialogs(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Bundle b = savedInstanceState.getBundle(SAVED_DIALOGS_TAG);
    if (b == null) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

This will cause `onCreateDialog` to not be called while restoring the Activity, effectively "hiding" any dialogs, thus preventing the scenario where one must return `null` from `onCreateDialog` from occurring.

This isn't a 'one size fits all' solution, but given my requirements it seems to fit the bill. By reviewing the code in grepcode for several platform versions (1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2.2, and 4.0.3), it appears that this solution should work consistently given these existing implementations.

Answer (score 11):

In API level 8, `onCreateDialog(int)` was [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int)) in favor of `onCreateDialog(int,Bundle)`.  If you implement only the latter method and run the app on a device with an API level lower than 8, you get the described error message.

The solution is to implement `onCreateDialog(int)`

Comment: Hi mndrix, my current target is 8 but my minversion is 3. I've updated the post with my onCreateDialog(int) implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For SDK version < 8, if you return null in onCreateDialog you get Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Great, could be that. Inside my dialog number 4, I had an internal checking and if it fails, it will return null. I that this could be the error. Although in the official documentation, there is the option of returning null http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html but I think that the issue is that previously, the app was able to show the dialog, then the user goes to another app, and when he returns back, the app tries to restore the dialog but this time returns null. I'll check it, thanks !

Comment: Here you can see it http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.createDialog%28java.lang.Integer%2Candroid.os.Bundle%29 . And for fix it, you need use method removeDialog, becouse this method remove your dialog from mManagedDialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented OnCreateDialog as presented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)? When you call showDialog(4) for the first time, OnCreateDialog(4) will be called and you need to create the dialog and return it from this method.

Comment: Yup, all the code is working perfectly fine. The application does not crash anywhere. I currently watch the dialogs poping and closing perfectly. The problem starts randomly when I restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly returning the dialog in `onCreateDialog`? If you were to do dialog.show() in dialog create but return some other dialog you could perhaps get a result like that.

Or are you doing any sort of manipulation in of the dialog object in `onPrepareDialog`

Comment: Yup, the dialog is created well with Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); ... ; return b.create(); Everytime that I show the dialog I call removeDialog(4) and then showDialog(4) because the content of the dialog changes. I do not override onPrepareDialog...